# Oracle SQL query question

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to extract data from database where field "end_ date" is less than today's date and where end_date is not equal to null; how would I do that? I figured the second part out .. I have trouble with first part

```
select * 
 from table 
where to_char(end_date) IS NOT null
```

Comment: You don't need to waste time converting the end date to a string to test it for null-ness; just use "WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
   ... 
   Where end_ date is not null and 
      And end_date < sysdate
```

And, actually, I think you may not even need the first part, as if end_date is null, it certainly will not be after todays date, so try this by itself:

```
Where end_date < sysdate
```

EDIT NOTEs:

1. This will give you every record that
   has an end_date prior to the current
   system date and time, including
   those with end_Date values earlier
   today.  If you want only those with
   end_Dates up to and *not* including
   midnight last night, then you need
   to replace "sysDate" with an
   expression for the date
   time value for midnight last night..

   Where end_date < trunc(sysdate)
2. ***sysdate*** is oracle specific syntax to return the current system date and time.  (in SQL Server, for e.g., it's a function called ***getDate()*** .  The ANSI-Standard Syntax for this functionality, (which works in both Oracle and SQL Server, and should work in any ANSI-standard database) is ***CURRENT_TIMESTAMP***.

Comment: +1: you don't need the "not null" part (since a NULL date would not be "less than sysdate")

Comment: Great explanation tnx a bunch

Answer (score 0):

To show you a little more on how to use the Dates in Oracle check this out:

Selects the current date and removes 30 minutes from it where check_date is declared as a timestamp.

```
select current_timestamp + interval '-30' minute into check_date from dual;
```

Selects everything from table where end_date is not null and above now - 30 minutes

```
select * from table
where to_char(end_date) is not null and end_date < check_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where end_date < CURRENT_DATE and end_date IS NOT null
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from table
where to_char(end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') is not null and end_date < sysdate;